# How to find href link with particular text with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python

```
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1591890/0001493152-18-003887-index.htm').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
# page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1591890/0001493152-18-003887-index.htm')

# soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
# Remove bottom links


for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True,text = re.compile('instance')):
    print link['href']
```

I am not getting any links upon running this.

Comment: I'm getting "NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined". Is ther something missing in your code?

Comment: @usr2564301 probably a Python version difference, `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`.

Comment: @BernardL: it's built in? It does not require any `import *something*`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your soup call to get 'href' keys of the  dictionary returned by findAll().  This should get what you need:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link['href'])
```